# Assigning input string value as datamember for example (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
public class Test {
    public bool Case1 { get; set; }
    public bool Case2 { get; set; }
    public bool Case3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I get input as Case1 as string

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {
    string test = "Case1";
}
```

In this particular case if I get input as Case1, I need to assign value of Test.Case1 as true.

Comment: You could use a switch statement, or a set of if statements, or reflection. What have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: Related: [`GetProperty()` via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .I have used switch and if statements, since I have 13 fields to set depending on these values, I was looking for some reusable code. I will try reflection if that serves the purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use reflection, it would look something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string test = "Case1";
    var myTest = new Test();
    var prop = myTest.GetType().GetProperty(test);
    prop.SetValue(myTest, true);
}
```

This is just a minimal example...in production code you'd want to have some error checking, for example to ensure that `prop != null` etc.